# Error: unexpected '=' in "aapl<-read.zoo("aapl.csv"+sep="

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to use the library "zoo" but I keep getting error messages even at the very start. I am using the book "Introduction to R in Quantitative Finance".

Here is my code:

```
>library("zoo")
Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

as.Date, as.Date.numeric

> aapl<-read.zoo("aapl.csv"+sep=",", header = TRUE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

Error: unexpected '=' in "aapl<-read.zoo("aapl.csv"+sep="
```

How do I fix this error? Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is a typo: `"aapl.csv"+sep=","` should be `"aapl.csv", sep=","`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aapl<-read.zoo("aapl.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: I get this error message:    

    Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
    In addition: Warning message:
    In file(file, "rt") :cannot open file 'aapl.csv': 
    No such file or directory

Comment: Is there a file called `aapl.csv` in your present working directory?

Comment: Yes, there is. Should I try moving the file to the desktop and change the working directory to the desktop? Or do you suggest another solution?

Comment: So, if you type `list.files()` you see it?

Comment: I just moved the file to another folder, and now it worked. And now I see it with that command. However, if I change my directory to "Documents", will R find the files and include all the sub folders within Documents?

Comment: It won't look in all the subdirectories. You will need to specify where the file is. For example, `./data/latest/aapl.csv`.